# How to set spam email using EWS api?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exchangewebservices

I am developing an email client using EWS api. I know for each item(email), I can use Move function to move the item into a specific folder. I noticed that in WellKnkownFolderName there is a JunkEmail. I wonder after is use Move function move that item into junkemail folder, does that mean the server will ban future emails coming from that sender?

```
 EmailMessage current = EmailMessage.Bind(service, id);
 current.Move(WellKnownFolderName.JunkEmail);//Does JunkEmail means spam? Or it is just a normal email folder as inbox, draft, sent etc
```

Answer (score 1):

No, Exchange will not automatically move future emails to the junk folder based on this mail.